# Metadata file not be found in csx file with VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, scripting, roslyn

I have researched the other answers to this question for couple of days and none of the solutions seem to work for my situation.

1. Error message: "error CS0006: Metadata file 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' could not be found"
2. Visual Studio 2019
3. .NET Core c# console project
4. Coding included in .csx files for scripting. Note the "Newtonsoft.Json" can be found in a .cs file.

[image]

Comment: Have the same issue, but don't want to provide a full path to a .dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by providing the full path to the dll file:
replacing 
     #r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" 
with 
     #r "c:\full_path\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

It appears with VS 2019, the CSX file does not know the path of dll added through NuGet, though it does recognize .NET libraries such as System.